# UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange enter value Between A to B

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a Problem in UITextField i want to enter Value between 1000 to 5000 only 
Here's my code whatever I tried is ?
This working fine but Problem is it's work only in 5 to 7 value's not more then length

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
  NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:_demo_str];
  for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
      return YES;
    }
    else
    {
      return NO;
    }
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: What's in _demo_str? And what do you mean "Problem is it's work only in 5 to 7 value's not more then length"?

Comment: @LyndseyScott _demo_str is string like in which values are showing as per condition like 1000 to 5000 number are in _demo_str ..."Problem is it not work more then length like 1000 to 5000

Comment: What happens if user enters 100 ?

Comment: So you're saying [1000, 1001, 1002, ..., 5000] are in _demo_str?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Here's my code  pastie.org/9762358 check this ...

Comment: @MidhunMP  pastie.org/9762358 check my code you understand what i have tried ?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Yes ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Midhum MP implied in his answer, the user will most likely enter the text characters one by one, so you can't let most numbers less than 5000 fail to meet the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` condition. For example, if the user enters 1, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` should return `YES` since the user could eventually go on to enter 1000. Technically, you could prevent a user from starting out the string with anything greater than 5 since there would ultimately be no four digit numbers starting with 6, 7, 8 or 9 that could meet the criteria.

But to keep things simple, I would recommend just limiting the text field entries to numbers less than 5000, ex:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    // First check whether the replacement string's numeric...
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    bool isNumeric = [string isEqualToString:filtered];

    // Combine the new text with the old
    NSString *combinedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ([combinedText intValue] <= 5000) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Then once the user has indicated they're finished by attempting to resign the text field as first responder, you could check to see whether the text entry in fact meets the condition. And if the condition isn't met, at that point, in `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`, you could force the keyboard to stay as the first responder until a valid number is entered, ex:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    int txtValue = [textField.text intValue];
    if (!(txtValue <= 5000 && txtValue >= 1000)) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to handle the current requirement using:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Because if user enters lesser value, your code will break. My suggestion is something like:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   int txtValue = [textField.text intValue];
   if (!(txtValue < 5000 && txtValue > 1000))
   {
       // Invalid value, show an alert
   }
}
```

Comment: The issue is, when you enter each character that method will be called. You can check the value greater than 5000 there, but can't handle the value less than 1000 values there. You can check it !